# How to set Intent in setOnClickListener in ViewPager2 in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, onclicklistener

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {
holder.imageView.setImageResource(imageList.get(position));

```
    if(position == imageList.size() - 2){
        viewPager2.post(runnable);
    }
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "You clicked on : " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(position == 0){
                Toast.makeText(viewPager2.getContext(), "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Activity_2.class);
                view.startActionMode((ActionMode.Callback) intent);
```

// startActivity(intent) , this class needs to be created it says

```
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Toasts addressed are shown but the intent in the same activity is not practised on the same position....the method of startActivity(intent) is also not recognised....please help

Answer (score 0):

Pass your activity to view pager adapter.

activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity,DestnationActivity,.class));

activity =  variable name for hold your activity

Answer (score -1):

Try With This Code

```
Context context;
Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Activity_2.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: but there is a correction:

Comment: Context context = view.getContext(); should be added....but still your idea helped a lot..